# Selecting greatest value of B for equal entries in A

Tags: oracle, plsql

Consider the following table:

```
  A  |  B
-----|------
 123 |  1
 456 |  2
 123 |  5
 456 |  0
 789 |  3
 789 |  9
 123 |  6
```

I want to get the following output:

```
  A  |  B
-----|------
 123 |  6
 456 |  2
 789 |  9
```

In other words: the greatest value of B for each equal value in A.

The initial table above comes already from another query which only selects duplicates of `A`:

```
select A, B from tbl where A in (
  select A from tbl
  group by A
  having count(A) > 1
);
```

I tried wrapping/integrating another `group`ing function with and without `max(B)` around/into this query, but no success.

How can I get the desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use max:

```
  select A, max(B) 
  from tbl
  group by A
  having count(A) > 1
```

Comment: Doh! Forgot to get rid of the outer query - I fixed it.

Comment: Now it works... Thanks! And well, I tried this already, but I can't trace back why it failed... I'm accepting your answer, because it is shorter than Brians, though the output of both your answers is the same.

Answer (score 1):

maybe I'm being naive here, but:

```
SELECT tbl2.A, MAX(tbl2.B) FROM
(select A, B from tbl where A in (
     select A from tbl
     group by A
     having count(A) > 1
)) as tbl2
GROUP BY tbl2.A
```

seems like it should work.

Comment: SQL Developer says that the `SQL command not properly ended`, although I put a `;` behind your query - am I missing something here?

Comment: Nevermind, I deleted the tablenaming (`tbl2`) and it works! Thanks! :)